# Match and lookup to find price

Tags: excel, match, lookup

I would be grateful if someone could help with the following.

I have a workbook (called passenger car comparison) that has a column of postcodes (B1) and then columns for different prices (C1:I1).

In a separate workbook (called Search Tool), I would like to display the post codes from B1 as a dropdown list, with the same row also displaying the prices from C1:I1 for that particular post code.

Would I need to use INDEX and MATCH or HLOOKUP? Confused!

There is a link to the spreadsheet [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=79B35E2AC1483838!190&authkey=!AK9eeduxFPOYcdE&ithint=file%2Cxlsx) if my explanation isn't clear!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use both.

However, you should use `VLOOKUP` instead of `HLOOKUP`, because your data elements are in rows, not columns. This is the most direct approach (`=VLOOKUP(DropDown,WholeTableFromBtoI,Line,FALSE)` - the `FALSE` here avoids linear interpolation with your postcodes). You can get your line from the row 1 of both cells, using `MATCH`, if you want to get fancy, by `=MATCH(Category,FirstLineOfTable,0)`.

And, If you intend to use `MATCH` straightforwardly, your better approach would be using `OFFSET` as well, as in `=OFFSET(FirstCellOfTable,MATCH(PostCode,PostCodeRow,0),MATCH(Category,FirstLineOfTable,0)`. It's a probably not the most intuitive approach, but it works as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Fernando, thank you for your advice. I used the VLOOKUP you mentioned but the data in each cell is incorrect - except for the first one. How do I always ensure that the lookup is performed on the left-most column?

Comment: The VLOOKUP always search on the leftmost column. I don't know if I understood your issue. Are you getting offset values, or incorrect ones?

Comment: Could you try the formula in the link to the spreadsheet? Only the first column links to the correct data.

Comment: Just did in the spreadsheet - I confess your explanation was clear enough, and I didn't follow the link (I'm in a very old macbook with Excel 2004, so it's mostly useless). It seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks. What's interesting is the data is only correct in the first three columns, the rest are random figures? So frustrating.

Comment: It seems correct to me. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, Fernando that did work. I had made a typo! Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi again, I'm having a little more trouble, this time with comparing the results in another workbook called 'Couriers Search Tool'. I can't replicate the formula.